# Is it possible to make orbit slider adjust to browser height

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

As in the title, I know it's responsive but when I put a basic orbit slider (outside "rows") it scales properly horizontally but want scale to adjust to the height of browser . Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the orbit-container a height of 100% it will adjust to its parent element's height. You just need to make sure that the parent element has a height that tracks with the window adjustment.